# Disable navigation and status bar in Android application

Tags: android

I want to permanently disable navigation and status bar for my android application i have used immersive mode for that but when i touch anywhere on screen the navigation and status bar reappears and on touching again on screen it goes back.I just want that all the navigation bar and status bar should not come when my application is running at any of the scenario please help.

Comment: Please help me in this

Comment: try my solution . this may works

Comment: it will hide only title bar not navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible without root. With root permission you can achieve this but still its not a preferred.

Comment: So how will i do that without root sir

Comment: So how to do with root

Comment: You need to edit this file programmatically 
http://www.androidexplained.com/how-to-disable-navigation-bar/

Comment: If i have to use a third party application like build prop editor why would i had asked this question i dont want to use any third party application